# How can I move he documentation to another location after install on Windows?

Tags: files-and-directories, windows

How can I move he documentation to another location after install on Windows?

I would like to move the documentation to another partition on my Windows filesystem. Michael Hale in chat recommended "Global Options -> File Locations -> SystemHelpPath". It looked like it would do the trick but after I added the folder and moved the files, clicking on "documentation" in the start screen returns

> "paclet:guide/WolframRoot" could not be found.

Windows version 8.1

Mathematica version 10.2

My "global preferences" and SystemHelpPath value, amended

http://ctrlv.in/777813

PS - what is the "x" in the last line of the SystemHepPath? I copied it directly from chat

Comment: Windows has symlinks like linux. Perhaps you can use that and don't tell Mathematica. http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/